# min-width and max-width issues. How to get inner content to grow with width

Tags: html, css

I have a three column site that will display all three columns or just one. If it displays just one column, my example below is the column it will be displaying. This `intro` wrapper is the center column that needs to grow in the event that the columns to the left and right of this wrapper are not present. Specifically, the first div in the intro wrapper. The second div has a static image in it and should not change.

I've used min/max-width but the content never reaches the maximum but rather stays at the minimum.

.intro is the wrapper. The min-width for this wrapper should be 801px and can grow up to a max of 1200px. The first inner div (`.intro-left`) should be a minimum of 531px and can grow up to a maximum of 979px.

Can someone have a look and tell me where I'm going wrong?

Here is my code.

```css
.intro{
  float:left;
  min-height:200px;
  width:801px;
  padding:10px 0;
}

.intro .intro-right{
  display:inline;
  float:left;
  height:200px;
  width:250px;
  background:#ccc;
}

.intro .intro-right img{
  height:190px;
  width:240px;
  margin:5px 0 0 5px;
  border:1px solid #777;
}

.intro .intro-left{
  display:inline;
  float:left;
  width:531px;
  min-height:200px;
  margin-right:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <div class="intro-left">
    <h2><a href="#">Test</a></h2>
    <p>test</p>
  </div>

  <div class="intro-right">
    <a href="#"><img alt="" src="1.jpg"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try overflow:hidden property.

Comment: I am having trouble deciding what your 3 columns are...? .intro-left, .intro-right, and what? Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DrCord/usELq/) to use to mess around with.

Comment: DrCord, thanks for the Fiddle. I've copied what you have and am trying to get this working locally. When I mentioned 3 columns, I was referring to the columns that sit to the left and right of the one that I've posted. The intro wrapper is the center column and the first div within that wrapper needs to be fluid. Referencing your Fiddle, the div with the blue outline is the one that needs to be fluid.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? I have a feeling your answer will revolve around `width: auto;` and `display: block;` anything width those two properties will take up all the width they can.

Answer (score 0):

display:table solves your issue,. here is the CSS, ive made some changes while testing that you may want to remove.. such as making the left div resizeable so that you can see it work in action.

```
div.intro {border:2px dotted red;
                min-height: 200px;
                max-width:1200px;
                min-width:801px;
                padding: 10px 0;
                margin:0 auto;
                display:table;

            }
            .intro-right, .intro-left{display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;}

            .intro-right {
                height: 200px;
                width: 250px;
                background: #ccc;
                outline: 2px solid green;
            }

            .intro-right img {
                height: 190px;
                width: 240px;
                margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
                border: 1px solid #777;
            }

            .intro-left {
                width: 531px;
                height: 200px;
                margin-right: 20px;
                outline: 2px solid blue;
                resize:both;
                overflow:auto;
            }
```

Comment: Luke, thanks for the answer. This still doesn't work as the `.intro-left` box doesn't grow when `div.intro` grows to 1200px. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: to solve that, I think you will need to use relative widths for .intro and .intro-left. such as width:100% for .intro and width:60% for .intro-left. that way they will grow/shrink as you resize the screen or when content is added to .intro-left